# Xamarin Forms - Listview is not scrolling and Click event also not getting fired

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am creating a `ListView` with one button inside. upon adding button the listview is not getting scrolled as well the itemselected method also not getting fired.

```xml
<Frame CornerRadius="20" 
    Padding="0" 
    Grid.Row="0">
    <ListView ItemSelected="ListViewOnItemSelected">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextCell Text="{Binding name}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Frame>
    <AbsoluteLayout Grid.Row="0" 
        x:Name="ViewControls">
        <Image Source="ic_add">
            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding AddHouseCommand}" 
                    NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
            </Image.GestureRecognizers>
        </Image>
```

as above in code i created a list with rows. when i add button the list view is not getting scrolled. and action event also not getting fired

Comment: I don't see any button in the code , where do you add it ?

Comment: Can you post your entire xaml?

Comment: Try changing `<AbsoluteLayout Grid.Row="0" x:Name="ViewControls">` to `<AbsoluteLayout Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ViewControls">`

Comment: You can just use a button inside your DataTemplate unless you use a custom cell instead with the help of a VewCell as shown here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-cell-appearance#custom-cells